# ionic v4 angular-router, how to hide restore google maps between view navigation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, angular-router

I'm trying to reuse the same instance of `google.maps.Map` when I navigate to/from a view with a MapComponent. When I leave/destroy the MapCompnent, I stash the google map DOM Element in a `DIV.style={display:none}`

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.map);
    const parent = this.element.nativeElement;
    let stash = document.getElementById('stash-google-maps');
    if (!stash) {
      stash = this.renderer.createElement('DIV');
      stash.id = 'stash-google-maps';
      stash.style.display = "none";
      // stash.style.opacity = "0";
      this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, stash);
    }
    while (parent.childNodes.length > 0) {
      stash.appendChild(parent.childNodes[0]);
    } 
  }
```

when I nav back to the view, I move the google map DOM Element back to the MapComponent html. Everything seems to work fine, EXCEPT the map size is wrong. The map is drawing tiles outside the new containing DIV.

I tried to call `google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');` but this seems to be deprecated in the current v3.34 API.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `new google.maps.Map( el, options)` is adding

```
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent element, `el`